# Django | How to query foreignkey and return only one object on a specific key (prefetch)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I am having a headache writing a query :slight_smile:
That’s my models:

```
`class Mission(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="missions")
    start_dt = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)

    @cached_property
    def timezone(self) -> datetime.tzinfo:
        timezone_str = get_tz(float(self.longitude), float(self.latitude))
        return pytz.timezone(timezone_str)`
```

and

```
`class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("updated at"), auto_now=True)`
```

I want to make a query with all the machines and for each machine a last_mission field where I have my last mission.

like:

`machine.last_mission.timezone ...`

.I am completely stuck doing it with the django ORM.

that’s my postgres query that doesn’t do exactly what I want as there is no last_mission key and not the model property.

Thanks a lot for you help :slight_smile:

`select * from machines_machine machine, missions_mission mission where (mission.machine_id, mission.start_dt)  in (select mission.machine_id as machine_id, Max(mission.start_dt) as start_dt  from missions_mission mission group by mission.machine_id  order by mission.machine_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate a json object with the latest mission inside a subquery:

```
latest_mission = Subquery(
    Mission.objects.filter(
        machine_id=OuterRef("id"),
    )
    .order_by("-start_dt")
    .values(
        mission=JSONObject(
            id="id", start_dt="start_dt", longitude="longitude", latitude="latitude"
        )
    )[:1]
)

machines = Machine.objects.all().annotate(latest_mission=latest_mission)
for machine in machines:
    print(machine.name, machine.latest_mission)
```

It should return something like:

```
AX001 {'id': 2, 'start_dt': '2021-02-01 01:00:00', 'longitude': 1, 'latitude': 1}
AX002 {'id': 4, 'start_dt': '2022-02-01 01:00:00', 'longitude': 1, 'latitude': 1}
```

The generated SQL query is:

```
SELECT "app_machine"."id", "app_machine"."name", "app_machine"."created_at", "app_machine"."updated_at", (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(id, U0."id", start_dt, U0."start_dt", longitude, U0."longitude", latitude, U0."latitude") AS "mission" 
    FROM "app_mission" U0 
    WHERE U0."machine_id" = ("app_machine"."id") 
    ORDER BY U0."start_dt" DESC LIMIT 1) AS "latest_mission"
FROM "app_machine"
```